# How to get the cell value from a table using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pick up values ​​from table cells that have text fields.

In my case I get results like:

```
input type="text" name="test1" onchange="myFunction()
```

but I want to get a value from a text field.

I have this function.

```
function GetTableCells(){
var oTable = document.getElementById('cell_values');
    //gets table

var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
//gets rows of table

for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){
//loops through rows

    var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
    //gets cells of current row
    var cellLength = oCells.length;
        for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){
        //loops through each cell in current row
            var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;

                    alert(cellVal);
        } } }
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to assign an ID to each input and retrieve it this way? `document.getElementById( "inputID" )`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var input = oCells[j].firstElementChild || oCells[j].firstChild;
var cellVal = input.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` gives you the HTML code but you want the value of an `input` element. To get the value, you need to iterate over the content of the cell and then use `e.value` when `e` is the node of the `input` element.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your event you can pass it into a function and get it there

```
<input type="text" name="test1" onchange="myFunction(this)">

myFunction(e){
  alert(e.value); // your value
}
```